# how do i do a combobox in the datagridview with a mysql command?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm developing an application and I got stuck on the way.
Currently im using this code

```
adapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id,description from xconfigwarehouses", connection)

table = New DataTable
adapter.Fill(table)
cmb_destino.DataSource = table
cmb_destino.DisplayMember = "description"
cmb_destino.ValueMember = "id"
cmb_destino.SelectedIndex = -1
```

---

to open  a normal combobox in the application but i wanted to add a column to a datagridview to became something similar
[image: combobox example]

the project is in visual basic

Comment: Take a look at this MSDN article: [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I recommend that you read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476). It's a how-to on this subject that I wrote some years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you have done, except with a datagridviewcombobox instead. Set the DataPropertyName property to the column name of the main table, if you plan on using the combo to update that main table being shown in the grid

Imagine the situation of a Person datatable with a column GenderId that is an int. Also a Gender table with N number of id:name pairs like 1:male, 2:female etc.

```
personDt = new DataTable
personAdapter.Fill(personDt)

genderDt = new DataTable
genderAdapter.Fill(genderDt)
```

Then the setup would be:

### DataGridView

- DataSource = personDt

### DataGridViewComboBox

- DataSource = genderDt
- DisplayMember = "name" 'e.g. "male", "female"
- ValueMember = "id" 'e.g. 1, 2
- DataPropertyName = "GenderId" 'the name of the column in personDt that shall link to

ComboBox becomes 2 way: when it finds `1` in the person gender, it looks it up and shows "male". When user changes item to "female" it gets associated 2 in genderDt.Id column and stores it to personDt.GenderId

Comment: hi, there many thanks for the directions that you give, im still having 1 critical error 
Value of type "DataTable" cannot be converted to "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn" maybe you can help me? , many thanks in advance

Comment: somewhere you've written `myDataGridViewComboBoxColumn = myDataTable` instead of (probably) `myDataGridViewComboBoxColumn .DataSource = myDataTable`